# Sum of coeficients

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

How to show that $\sum |c_{n}|^{2} = 1$ ?

Where, $\psi = \sum <c_{n}|e_{n}>$ (completeness)

and $e_{n}$ are the eigenvectors of the general operator $Q$ (with discrete spectra)

I started as below:

$c_{n} = <e_{n}|\psi>$, so $c^{2} = <e_{n}|\psi><e_{n}|\psi>$, but not sure how to go on here...

Answer (score 0):

You start with the requirement that the wave function is normalized:
$$
\langle \psi |\psi\rangle = 1
$$

Comment: Yeh, i get now... Thank you guys.

Comment: @LSS there is no shame in asking simple questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference between $c^2$ and $\vert c\vert^2$ since
$c^*=\langle\psi\vert e_n\rangle$.  In particular, you can use the resolution the identity $\hat{\mathbb{I}}=\sum_n \vert e_n\rangle\langle e_n\vert$.

Answer (score 0):

$|\psi \rangle = \sum_n c_n |e_n \rangle$. Now by normalization $1 = \langle \psi|\psi \rangle = \sum_{m,n} c_n^\star c_m \langle e_n|e_m \rangle$. Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Start from
$$
|c_n|^2= \langle \psi|n\rangle \langle n |\psi\rangle
$$
(this is *not* what you have)
Then, by the spectral theorem for self-adjoint opertors, the states $|n\rangle$ form a orthonormal complete set so
$$
|\psi\rangle= \sum_n|n\rangle\langle n|\psi\rangle,
$$
for any state $|\psi\rangle$.
This  is often written as
$$
{\rm id}= \sum_n  |n\rangle \langle n |,
$$
where ${\rm id}$ is the identity operator.
The dual "bra" state is expanded as
$$
\langle \psi|= \sum_n\langle \psi|n\rangle\langle n|
$$
Thus
$$
\sum_n |c_n|^2= \sum_{n,m} \langle \psi|n\rangle \langle n |m\rangle\langle m| \psi\rangle\\
=\sum_{n} \langle \psi|n\rangle \langle n| \psi\rangle\\
= \langle \psi|\psi\rangle.
$$
We have used $\langle n|m\rangle= \delta_{nm}$, so
this result does *not* hold for a general operator $Q$ -- even if it is diagonalizable. The operator has to be self-adjoint (hermitian) so that  the eigenstates are mutually orthogonal.